# Related to Proposition 2.1.1 in Diamond 's Modular Forms

Tags: modular-forms

The following is from Diamond and Shurman's *A First Course in Modular Forms* book:

[image]
[image]

I can't understand not even a fraction of all of underlined statements:

1- How homeomorphism comes out?

2- How Prop. 2.1.1 is related to?

Simple clear explanation would be much appreciated.

Comment: To make things concrete take $\Gamma =SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$, $V = \{ \Im(\tau) > 0, \Re(\tau) \in (0,1), |\tau| > 1\}$. Then $\pi : \tau \mapsto \{ \gamma(\tau), \gamma \in \Gamma\}$ is biholomorphic $V \to \pi(V) \subset Y$. Then do the same with $3$ open sets containing the boundary of $V$ to obtain a covering of $Y$ by the images of (finitely many) biholomorphic functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we are trying to make the topological space $Y(\Gamma)$ into a one dimensional complex manifold.  This means that we are trying to cover $Y(\Gamma)$ with charts, which are pairs $(V, \varphi)$ consisting of an open set $V$ of $Y(\Gamma)$ together with a homemorphism $\varphi$ of $V$ with an open subset of $\mathbb C$.

Let $\tau$ be an element of $\mathcal H$, so that $\pi(\tau)$ is an element of $Y(\Gamma)$.  In your question, we are considering the special case where the only elements of $\Gamma$ which fix $\tau$ are $\pm I$ (or just $I$ if $-I \not\in \Gamma$).  We will now construct a chart $(V,\varphi)$ in $Y(\Gamma)$ such that $\pi(\tau) \in V$.

Applying Proposition 2.1.1 (with $\tau_1 = \tau_2 = \tau$), take $U$ to be the intersection of the two open neighborhoods $U_1$ and $U_2$ of $\tau$.  Then $U$ is a neighborhood of $\tau$ with the property that if $\gamma \in \Gamma$, and $\gamma(U) \cap U \neq \emptyset$, then $\gamma(\tau) = \tau$.

But for $\gamma \in \Gamma$, our hypothesis on $\tau$ is that $\gamma(\tau)$ is never equal to $\tau$, unless $\gamma = \pm I$, which case $\gamma$ fixes every point of $\mathcal H$.    Therefore, $\gamma(U)$ is disjoint from $U$, except if $\gamma = \pm I$.

This implies that the restriction of $\pi$ to $U$ is a bijection of $U$ onto $\pi(U)$.  Of course this is surjective; to show that it is injective, suppose that $\pi(\tau') = \pi(\tau'')$ for $\tau', \tau'' \in U$.  Then there exists a $\gamma \in \Gamma$ such that $\gamma(\tau') = \tau''$, which implies that $\gamma(U) \cap U \neq  \emptyset$.  This then implies that $\gamma = \pm I$, hence $\tau' = \tau''$.

Now, $\pi$ is moreover a homeomorphism of $U$ onto $\pi(U)$.  This is because $\pi: \mathcal H \rightarrow Y(\Gamma)$ is an *open* map.  Thus $\varphi = \pi^{-1}: \pi(U) \rightarrow U$ together with $\pi(U)$ is a chart.

Comment: Sorry, off-topic but could you tell me how could you understand the text (in the question) i.e. I've studied Munkres' Topology but I have difficulties understanding Diamond's Modular Forms but I could understand your answer! Better said: is there any book that I need to study before Diamond's Modular Forms? (Not Serre's arithmetic: a useless book). Thanks a lot in advance :-)

Comment: ... I am self-studying Diamond's Modular Forms as I did for many books in other areas so I don't say that I can't afford a book if it isn't a spoon-feeding; but still Diamond's book either assumes previous book(s) or unreadable at all.

Comment: I don't think there's any book in particular that is prerequisite to this.  But as you do more math over time, you will become more experienced and you can learn to rely on your intuition/plethora of memorized facts you have encountered before, and the easier it becomes reading these proofs.

Comment: For example, I was not worried or confused about $U \rightarrow \pi(U)$ being a homeomorphism, even if I could not immediately recall the reason why this is.  Just because I have seen similar situations to this (various groups acting on various topological spaces) a bajillion times before.

Comment: You are doing great, by the way.  I hope you continue reading about modular forms and posting questions on here about the technical details when you are frustrated.

Comment: Thank you so much! I found a book easier than Diamond's which is Stein's Modular Forms. It's a bit more readable and will come back to Diamond's after finishing it. :)